# How to let user sign in through a browser

Tags: ios, github-api

I use `OctoKit` library to access API of github , but how can I  implement a custom URL scheme in iOS (I don't know how to let user sign in through a browser )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50) describes how to implement custom URL schemes.